# Is there any option to get actual execution plan as xml value to insert do different table?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

Do you know If there is any option to get actual execution plan

[image]

and insert this plan to another table ? I would like to have table with history of actual plans.

Answer (score 0):

Among other options to answer the question strictly as asked, I suggest you look into [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store). Brent Ozar has a good writeup on it [on his blog](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/sql-server-query-store/), but the salient bullet points copy-pasted from there are:

> - ...Query Store ... cache[s] queries and execution plans even after they’ve changed (like due to a statistics change on a table)
> - These changes may even persist beyond a SQL Server restart (meaning they’ll have to be written to disk somewhere)
> - The current and prior plans will be exposed in a DMV for you to query (meaning you might be able to roll your own alerts when a plan changes so you can check out whether it’s better or worse)

If Query Store is available on your version of SQL Server and you choose to deploy it, you can use the built-in GUI to browse plans. If you want to write a query to get the plans back as you describe, the DMV you'll want is (IIRC) [sys.query_store_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think is it also possible to retrive actual execution plan from `Query Store` ?